# Confusion with using singular or plural

Tags: grammatical-number

What's correct 
"A, B and one other alphabet have been updated" 
or 
"A, B and one other alphabets have been updated"

Comment: Did you mean "alphabet" as in the concept of a grouping of letters? Or did you mean "letter"?

Comment: Okay, no worries. I'll update my answer. But see [this link](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet). It's the page for "alphabet" on the Simple English Wikipedia. That should explain why I was a bit confused with your usage. :)

Comment: Yup. I too went and clarified the difference between letter and alphabet. Turns out in standard English alphabet is a collection of letters !! Thanks once again!!

Comment: No problem! I've updated my answer to use "letter", but the gist is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment, I think you intended your sentence to be:

> A, B and one other letter have been updated.

Here, "one other letter" is considered a single [*noun phrase*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase). It is separate from A and B. Therefore, your sentence is correct.

One way to adjust the sentence is to add an extra comma, called the ["serial comma"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma). In my opinion, this makes the distinction a bit more obvious:

> A, B, and one other letter have been updated.

(Note that use of the serial comma — or "Oxford comma" as it is colloquially known — is a matter of personal preference. I just happen to like it.)